# Workflow does not starts for all created items

Tags: workflow

I have created workflow for Document library.

I checked these options for workflow:

- Allow this workflow to be manually started by an authenticated user with Edit Items Permissions.
- Start this workflow when a new item is created.
- Start this workflow when an item is changed.

  Workflow is starting successfully for some items.

**What is the reason workflow is not getting started for some newly created item?

My second question is what can be the reason for workflow suddenly stops automatic start for lists?**

Comment: Are you creating the items with System Account when the Workflow doesn't execute? It was a security check introduced in SharePoint 2010, if you are using System Account.. The workflows won't fire.. Try using any other account

Comment: No. I am not using system account. Workflow sometimes starts or sometimes does not starts. At least it should not start for some new entries. So I think this issue is not related with the SYSTEM ACCOUNT.


I have another workflow, which suddenly stopped starting for newly created items. what could be the reason?

Comment: I don't suppose these items are document sets? Document sets don't fire item added events.

Comment: Is there any situation like workflows stops working suddenly? If yes, how it should be solved?

Comment: Try reviewing Workflow Scalability and Performance:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441390(v=office.12).aspx